# Using mathjax: local in a bookdown project

Tags: bookdown

The server where I house my bookdown html no longer permits external source calls, so the part of index.html at the end that seems to be the issue is

```
var src = "true";
    if (src === "" || src === "true") src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.9/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML";
```

Following [the bookdown instructions](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#mathjax-equations) I added to the index.Rmd yaml header:

```
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: local
    self_contained: false
```

However, the external mathjax reference persisted. To make a reproducible example, I created a bookdown skeleton using

```
bookdown:::bookdown_skeleton(getwd())
```

By default it includes the same external reference as above. Adding

```
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: local
    self_contained: false
```

to the yaml header of index.Rmd or to the _output.yml section following `bookdown::gitbook:` (or both) does not install the local mathjax lib or remove the external reference from the html. Am I just putting that in the wrong place? I have used this process to remove external references from a Rmarkdown document and a website written in Rmarkdown successfully, but how to do this with my bookdown project has not been successful and I do not know why.